# Error when making random errors in Python

Tags: python, variables, random

> ```
> import random
> import time
> loop = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
> queenstrength = 100
> queendamagenum = 1,20
> print "The queens health is currently: ",queenstrength
>
> while queenstrength > 0:
>     queendamage = random.randint((queendamagenum))
>     print""
>     print "queen damage:", queendamage
>     queenstrength = queenstrength - queendamage
>     print queenstrength
>     time.sleep(1)
>
> print""
> print"finished"
> ```

I'm trying to use this code in a game I am making, but I keep getting the error:

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 9, in <module>
    queendamage = random.randint((queendamagenum))
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)**
```

what does it mean 3 arguments (2 given)? I thought it only needed a min and a max?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[randint](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint) accepts a min and a max, like this:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.randint(0,10)
1
```

but you're passing a tuple:

```
>>> random.randint((0, 10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

You can use [argument unpacking (](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)the * operator) to turn your tuple into a series of arguments for randint, if you like:

```
>>> queendamagenum = 1, 20
>>> random.randint(*queendamagenum)
8
```

As for the fact that the error message says "3 arguments (2 given)", that's because randint is actually a method living in an instance of random.Random, and not a function.  methods automatically get an argument passed to them (traditionally called "self") which is the instance itself.  So you should translate "3 arguments (2 given)" into "2 non-self arguments (1 given)", and you only passed it 1 tuple, so that make sense.

Comment: +1. Btw., the third argument is implicit; `random.randint` is actually an instance method on a hidden singleton object.

Comment: @larsmans: hey, I can't type as fast as you five-digit-karma types: :^)